# How would I go about making these seem more like planets?

Tags: rendering, texturing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Kqa.jpg)

[image: **enter image description here**]

So I recently created this images in blender using some mapping and some planet maps I got online. My question is how would I go about making these planets appear more realistic. Currently they look like circle no matter which way I angle the camera. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What renderer are you using? Blender internal or Cycles?

Comment: Im using blender render at the moment, would you think it would be better if I tried to do it in cycles?

Comment: Cycles has a more realistic result. But in your case the Blender internal can give almost the same result as Cycles.

Comment: I will edit my answer with a solution for blender internal.

Comment: What is the difference between a flat disc and a sphere? When represented in an image in two dimensions there is no difference: they both become circles. The way we would perceive volume and shape is through light and shadow. If the light is coming from every direction equally or from behind the camera there is no way to understand volume. Add a light source that helps to reveal the spherical shape of your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Internal renderer:

[image]

Add a direction light and give your sphere a new material. Turn the Specular -> Intensity down to 0.
[image]

And add your texture. Result:

[image]

For the Cycles renderer:

[image]

Add a directional light. And give the material a diffuse shader like this:
[image]

In the Image Texture node you can put your texture. (Don't forget to UV unwrap your spheres)
This is the result without a texture:

[image]